# Storing Session using Memcached in JBoss AS7

Tags: session, memcached, jboss7.x

In Tomcat, session manager attribute can be given in the context.xml of server.So in JBoss where it can be given - standalone.xml ? Does it support Context descriptor ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. create an implementation of the org.jboss.as.clustering.web.DistributedCacheManagerFactory interface (and all dependent interfaces)
2. create a module that defines a META-INF/services/org.jboss.as.clustering.web.DistributedCacheManagerFactory file that points to your implementation
3. replace the default implementation (org.jboss.as.clustering.web.infinispan) in $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/jboss/as/clustering/web/spi/main/module.xml with your custom module.

There are now 2 msm jars you have to put into lib: the core msm jar and the jboss specific one:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1439289/msm-all-memcached-session-manager-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1439289/msm-all-memcached-session-manager-jbossweb2-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

source links look [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/context.html) and [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/796157#796157)